# Firebase give error 400 Bad request but login sucessfuly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a login page with ReactJS and Firebase and when I click to login, I first have a error 400 and a sucessful login. Is it normal ? If not how to fix it ? I use the default code that is in the Firebase documentation.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

This is what the result in the console:

[image]

Comment: If the API works as you expect, is there really a problem?

Comment: no but if it works, why is there a error then ?

Comment: Well, we can't see the error, so we don't know what it was trying to do or where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear why you got an error. However, creating a login page with React and Firebase is more than one line of code. Check the documentation below for more info regarding the topic:
https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial